# I need to know how to render the html iframe element from a rich text format

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, strapi, mdxjs

I am reviewing the Strapi tutorial on building a blog with Nextjs with Strapi. [tutorial here](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-with-next-react-js-strapi)

They indicate that a package for the markdown format must be downloaded.
[image]

And here is where it is used: 
[image: article/slug]

And the result is this:
[image]
I just took a screenshot where the iframe element is not rendering. What I think is that it is necessary to use a tool that works for mdx but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rehype-raw package

1. npm install rehype-raw
2. `<ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} children={input} />`